# Show dialog on homescreen when app is paused

Tags: android, overlay

I have application, where I use OverlayService to draw "allways-on-top" icon. I want to show dialog (custom view), when I click on this icon. The problem is, when the application is paused - nothing happens when I click to icon, because application is not responding to events, when is paused. Could you help me? Thanks.

```
public class OverlayService extends Service {

private WindowManager wm;
private ImageView imageView;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

    params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE;
    params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
    params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    sendResultMessage( Constant.FAB_ICON_ONCLICK, "FAB icon onclicked.");

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.d("OverlayService", "click");
            sendResultMessage( Constant.FAB_ICON_ONCLICK, "FAB icon onclicked.");
        }
    });

    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    imageView.performClick();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX - (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    wm.updateViewLayout(imageView, params);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    wm.addView(imageView, params);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    removeView();
}

private void removeView() {
    if (imageView != null) {
        wm.removeView(imageView);
    }
}

private void sendResultMessage(int cmd, String data) {
    Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting result message: " + data);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Constant.FILTER);
    intent.putExtra(Constant.COMMAND, cmd);
    intent.putExtra(Constant.DATA, data);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}

```
public class StepsFragment extends DialogFragment {
public static String LOG_TAG = "StepsFragment";
private TextView stepsText;
Button closeButton;
Button prevButton;
Button nextbutton;
Button stopRecordingFromStepsFragment;
ArrayList<String> tasks = new ArrayList<String>();
TextView currentStepTextView;

public StepsFragment() {
    // Empty constructor is required for DialogFragment
    // Make sure not to add arguments to the constructor
    // Use `newInstance` instead as shown below
}

public static StepsFragment newInstance(String title) {
    StepsFragment frag = new StepsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(RecordingActivity.TEST_TITLE, title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.steps_fragment, container);

    closeButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
    prevButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.prevButton);
    nextbutton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    stopRecordingFromStepsFragment = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopRecordingFromStepsFragment);
    currentStepTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.currentStepTextView);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        tasks = bundle.getStringArrayList(WebViewFragment.TASKS_API_RESPONSE);

        if(tasks == null){
            tasks = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }

    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final View decorView = getDialog()
                    .getWindow()
                    .getDecorView();

            ObjectAnimator scaleDown = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(decorView,
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1.0f, 0.0f),
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1.0f, 0.0f),
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("pivotX", 900f),
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("pivotY", 150f),
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("alpha", 1.0f, 0.0f)
                    );
            scaleDown.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                }
            });
            scaleDown.setDuration(1000);
            scaleDown.start();
        }});

    prevButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onPrevButtonClicked(v);
        }});

    nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onNextButtonClicked(v);
        }});

    stopRecordingFromStepsFragment.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           onStopButtonClicked();
        }});

    initializeStopBtnInsteadOfNext();

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    currentStepTextView.setText( currentStepStringValue(WebViewFragment.stepsIndex , tasks.size()));

    // Get field from view
    stepsText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.stepsText);
    stepsText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    setStepsText();
    // Fetch arguments from bundle and set title
    String title = getArguments().getString(RecordingActivity.TEST_TITLE, "");
    getDialog().setTitle(title);
    // Show soft keyboard automatically and request focus to field
    stepsText.requestFocus();
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
}

private String currentStepStringValue(int stepsIndex, int tasksSize){
    return "Step " + (stepsIndex + 1) + " out of " + tasksSize;
}

@Override
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {

    try {
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(this, tag);
        ft.commit();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Exception", e);
    }
}

private void setStepsText(){
    if (WebViewFragment.stepsIndex < tasks.size()  ){
        String taskDesc = tasks.get(WebViewFragment.stepsIndex);
        stepsText.setText(taskDesc);
    }
}

public void onCloseButtonCliked(View v){
    dismiss();
}

public void onPrevButtonClicked(View v){
    if (WebViewFragment.stepsIndex> 0){
        WebViewFragment.stepsIndex -=1;
        setStepsText();

        currentStepTextView.setText( currentStepStringValue(WebViewFragment.stepsIndex , tasks.size()));
        nextbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        stopRecordingFromStepsFragment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public void onNextButtonClicked(View v){
    if (WebViewFragment.stepsIndex< this.tasks.size()){
        WebViewFragment.stepsIndex +=1;
        setStepsText();
        currentStepTextView.setText( currentStepStringValue(WebViewFragment.stepsIndex , tasks.size()));

        initializeStopBtnInsteadOfNext();
    }
}

private void initializeStopBtnInsteadOfNext(){
    if (WebViewFragment.stepsIndex == this.tasks.size() - 1){
        nextbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        stopRecordingFromStepsFragment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

private void onStopButtonClicked(){
    if (WebViewFragment.stepsIndex == this.tasks.size() - 1 ){
        WebViewFragment.myChronometer.stop();
        callStopInRecordingActivity();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.string.not_completed_all_steps , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void callStopInRecordingActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RecordingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(WebViewFragment.CALL_ON_STOP_RECORDING, WebViewFragment.CALL_ON_STOP_RECORDING);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onResume() {
    // Store access variables for window and blank point
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    Point size = new Point();
    // Store dimensions of the screen in `size`
    Display display = window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(size);
    // Set the width of the dialog proportional to 85% of the screen width
    window.setLayout((int) (size.x * 0.85), (int) (size.y * 0.85));
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    // Call super onResume after sizing
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final View decorView = getDialog()
            .getWindow()
            .getDecorView();

    ObjectAnimator scaleDown = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(decorView,
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 0.0f, 1.0f),
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 0.0f, 1.0f),
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("alpha", 0.0f, 1.0f));
    scaleDown.setDuration(1000);
    scaleDown.start();
}
```

}

```
public class WebViewActivity extends MainActivity {
boolean showOverlayService = false;
public final static int REQUEST_CODE = 15;
public static String LOG_TAG = "WebViewActivity";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_empty);
    super.onCreateDrawer();

    showOverlayService = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(RecordingActivity.RUN_OVERLAY_SERVICE, false);

    if (showOverlayService){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            checkDrawOverlayPermission();
        }
        else {
            startOverlayService();
        }
    }


    Fragment fragment = new WebViewFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onStart()");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((mMessageReceiver), new IntentFilter(Constant.FILTER));
    // The activity is about to become visible.
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onStop()");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    // The activity is no longer visible (it is now "stopped")
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // intentionally blank
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ) {

}

private void checkDrawOverlayPermission() {
    /** check if we already  have permission to draw over other apps */
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        /** if not construct intent to request permission */
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        /** request permission via start activity for result */
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    startOverlayService();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  Intent data) {
    /** check if received result code
     is equal our requested code for draw permission  */
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            // continue here - permission was granted
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startOverlayService(");
            startOverlayService();
        }
    }
}

private void startOverlayService(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OverlayService.class);
    intent.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras());
    startService(intent);
}

private void onFabClick(){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList(WebViewFragment.TASKS_API_RESPONSE, getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra(RecordingActivity.TEST_TASKS));

    StepsFragment stepsFragment = StepsFragment.newInstance(getIntent().getStringExtra(RecordingActivity.TEST_TITLE));
    stepsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    stepsFragment.show(fm, "steps_fragment");
}

/*
 *  SERVICE COMMUNICATORS
 */
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Got message");
        handleMessage(intent);
    }
};

/*
 * Handle message from services
 */
private void handleMessage(Intent msg) {
    Bundle data = msg.getExtras();

    switch (data.getInt(Constant.COMMAND, 0)) {
        case Constant.FAB_ICON_ONCLICK:
            onFabClick();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can also use BroadcastReceiver and make sure you are registering it !
and then if you use dialog copy the below code to your dialog code .

```
yourDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

And add the permission into your **manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Don't forget to implement code to check permission on android 6.0.1 .